# How to return IEnumerable<Class> from Grid Kendo to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I load information to a grid Kendo, and the user can changes values of multiple employees, then click on a button for save changes. I want to return the information (list) to the controller for do the update.

Model:

```
 public class AuthorizationModel
{
    [Editable(false)]  
    [Display(Name = "No. Nómina")]
    public int idRoster { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]  
    [Display(Name="Empleado")]
    public string  employee { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estatus")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comentarios")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string comment { get; set; }

   ..............//property
   ..............//property
}
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpGet()]
    [Route("Autorizacion")]
    [Authorize()]
    public ActionResult Authorization()
    {
        _orderBLL = new OrderBLL();
        var models = new List<AuthorizationModel>();
        var orders = _orderBLL.GetPendingOrders();
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            var model = new AuthorizationModel();

            model.idRoster = int.Parse(order.NUMNOM_CTE);
            model.employee = order.NOMBREEMPLEADO;
            //other properties
            if (order.ESTFIN_AUI.ToUpper()== "P")
            model.status = "Pendiente";

            models.Add(model);
        };

        return View(models);
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("Autorizacion")]
    public ActionResult Authorization(IEnumerable<AuthorizationModel> model)
    {
     //do something with the Information
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ElizondoMX.Models.Order.AuthorizationModel>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using ElizondoMX.Telerik.Extensions;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

      @using (Html.BeginForm("Authorization", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<body>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
           .Name("OrdersGrid")
           .Columns(columns =>
           {
               columns.Bound(c => c.idRoster).Title("No. Nómina");
               columns.Bound(c => c.employee).Title("Empleado");
               columns.BoundActionLink((item) => item.idOrder, "Detail", "Order", (item) => new { id = item.idOrder });
               columns.Bound(c => c.status).Title("Estatus").EditorTemplateName("StatusDropDown");
               columns.Bound(c => c.comment).Title("Comentarios");
           })
           .Excel(excel => excel
               .FileName("Elizondo_Pedidos.xlsx")
               .Filterable(true)
            )
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Selectable(s => s.Enabled(true)
                            .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
                            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
           .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Excel().Text("Exportar a excel"))
           .Sortable()
           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto;margin: 0px;" })
           .DataSource(datasource => datasource
               .Ajax()
               .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
               .Model(model=>  model.Id(p => p.idRoster))
               .Read(read=> read.Action("Authorization", "Order"))
           ))
    <input type="submit"  value="Actualizar Estatus" class="btn btn-primary" />
</body>
      }
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do Batch edit ? If so https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing

Comment: Something like that. Then Save Changes, I want to refresh the grid for show only the rows with status "Pending".